# Background Worker is Running but Doesn't Print anything

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` called `bgw` to whom I pass my custom `Form` called `LogBoxForm` to. The custom `Form` job is simply to print something on it.

```
LogBoxForm logBox = new LogBoxForm(); //both declared in the main Form
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
```

In the main `Form`'s `Load` `event` initiated the two `bgw` events: `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` like this

```
bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

And then when I pressed a `Button` named `button9`, the `bgw` will be ran as directed by this code

```
//Background worker
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (bgw.IsBusy)
        return;
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync(logBox);
}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    LogBoxForm lbf = e.Argument as LogBoxForm;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            lbf.WriteTimedLogLine("loop " + (i + 1).ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw exc;
    }
}

void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    logBox.WriteTimedLogLine("Completed!");
    if (e.Error != null)
        logBox.WriteTimedLogLine(e.Error.ToString());
}
```

It stops in the `catch` line This is the error message I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'richTextBoxAll' accessed from a thread other than the thread
>   it was created on.

I am pretty new user for `BackgroundWorker` and may not really be aware how all these can happen. I am hoping that some more experienced can tell what is wrong with my code. I am looking forward for your guidance.

Comment: If you catch an exception in your DoWork event handler then it is your job to report the exception.  That `text` variable assignment in your catch clause does nothing.  Remove try/catch to trivially get ahead.

Comment: You can't update the UI in background thread. You'll get `InvalidOperationException`. You can find it by adding a breakpoint in catch block

Comment: @HansPassant you are right, actually the text means nothing here, it is just how normally I put my break point to debug (as opposed to normally people put in the catch line)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the `bgw` never reach my break point in the `catch` as I debug, Sir. How could that be? Somemore, I passed the `logBox` as argument when I started the `bgw` `Async` (notice `button9_Click` `event`). Is that not allowed? I am pretty new to `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: What does `WriteTimedLogLine` method look like? I'm guessing you have a catch statement in that method also

Comment: @HansPassant if the `bgw` throw an `exception` in the `catch`, where is it actually caught?

Comment: The DoWork event is raised in code that uses try/catch.  So *any* exception is always caught, it sets the e.Error property that is passed to your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: I think exception occurred in Typecasting LogBoxForm lbf = e.Argument as LogBoxForm;

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ah yes! You cannot be more accurate. It was in my library and when I checked the `code` it has `try-catch` that does not throw exception (capture internally). I changed it to throw exception already. And when I check the error code after changing the `catch` in the `DoWork` to throw its exception, it prints out as `System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBoxAll' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on` so, how do I fix this?

Comment: In bgw_DoWork you are converting the arg to LogBoxForm (lbf) but you are not using it... (it don't solve your problem but, if you are not using it you don't need to send through parameters)

Comment: @ConradoCosta My bad, I changed it to `lbf` but still got the same error. Anyway, I will update my question to its latest state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a classic case of Thread Affinity. Since the `BackgroundWorker` runs on a different thread other than the UI thread you need to call `.Invoke`.  Checkout this link [here](https://onlycsharp.wordpress.com/sharpening/extension-methods/) to see an example of an extension method that encapsulates thread-safe invocation.

With this extension method you can write WinForms thread-safe code like this:

```
this.ThreadSafeInvoke(() => logBox.WriteTimedLogLine("loop " + (i + 1).ToString()));
```

The key here is that since your execution on a different thread, the `.InvokeRequired` bool will return true and then you'll execute the `Action` passed into the `ThreadSafeInvoke` via the `.Invoke` -- which will marshal back to the UI thread.

If you do not want to have an extension method simply do the following instead:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
                logBox.WriteTimedLogLine("loop " + (i + 1).ToString())));
```

The advantages to the extension method are obvious. I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, suggesting a fix. Give me a moment, I will try it out.

Comment: How do we use this `ThreadSafeInvoke`? What does `this` refer to? In my context, that will be `MainForm` is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is fine -- it would also work if you did this `logBox.ThreadSafeInvoke(() => logBox.WriteTimedLogLine("loop " + (i + 1).ToString()))`.  Look at the link I posted, its an extension method I created years ago.  ThreadSafeInvoke extends Control. So any control can call it...

Comment: In the end, I tried to use this line first `this.Invoke(() => lbf.WriteTimedLogLine("loop " + (i + 1).ToString()));` (nevertheless I copied your method too, thanks!) But I get compilation error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to `System.Delegate` because it is not a delegate type` how do we handle it?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I simply forgot the MethodInvoker, it is the same regardless of .NET version.  The MethodInvoker, unlike a lambda is explicit -- and with lambda's the compiler complains as it considers the expression to be a Function<string>

Comment: it works like magic! Thanks! So, does that mean that as long as we have a  method which we want to call, we could simply do `this.Invoke` and the method would be ran in its owner class safely? What does your `ThreadSafeInvoke` do?

Comment: I would suggest ThreadSafeInvoke as it has lots of checks that are beneficial.  If you call .Invoke on the UI thread it will throw.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have accepted it a couple of minutes ago. But maybe it takes some time before it gets updated in your place.

Comment: The method to call your `ThreadSafeInvoke` which you show doesn't seem to work correctly. When I used it, it says that `ThreadSafeInvoke` doesn't take one argument. And when I changed to be like this `this.ThreadSafeInvoke(() => lbf, lbf.WriteTimedLogLine("loop " + (i + 1).ToString()));` it says `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' because it is not a delegate type` any idea?